# How to count the number of breakline in td

Tags: php, tcpdf

I would like to ask how to count the break line in `<td>` if the value in `<td>` is too long.. like sample description of item.

SAMPLE

```
<table width="50px">
<tr><td>SDsdfsdfds asdfasdjhkasjhdk asdjkasdkjask ajksdkjasdj asdasdasdas asdasdasd dssfdsf sfdsdfs dfsdfsd fsdf sdfs dfsd fsdf sdfs dfsd sfsdfsd fsdgdgsdfsdfsd fsdfsdfsdf sdfsdf sdfsd fsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfdsfds sdffsdfsdfdsfdsfdsfds sdfsd</td></tr>
</table>
```

the output will be unknown how many `br` will be in `td`

Comment: but in your sample, there is no <br> :P

Comment: `$("td").find("br").length`

Comment: right sir... i think my asking not clear... sample the table is 50px you have long value... how to count how many line in td?... other called is breakline in td

Comment: If I understand correctly. You want to count how many lines the sentence will break after it wrapped the sentence. Am I right?

Comment: could be... how many line it will be if it output in td or div with 50px width

Comment: since you're not specifying a delimiter like putting a `<br>` on the sentence because it only depends on how the sentence will be wrapped and  as far as I know, the sentence will be break by space if given an exact size of width. Even if it uses space as delimiter, it would still be impossible to know how many lines it will break because it also depends on how long or short the word might be. So I think what you want to achieve is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it through jquery, count the number of br tags under a particular id or div.(indexOf might help you).